# Clean Sand from bottom of a 5000-gallon drinking water storage tank

Tags: water

I have drinking water storage tanks around 3500 and 5000 gallons for house water. The well pump has pumped mostly sand and very small gravel into the tank from the underground aquafer from the 200-foot 15hp well. The tanks now have about 2 inches deep of sand that I need to remove.  The tanks are about 20 feet in diameter and about 7 feet high to the manhole cover at the top.  I can lower the water level in the tank to about 6 inches. I want to vacuum/remove the sand from the bottom of the tanks without climbing into the tanks similar to a pool type vacuum.

Comment: So what is the issue here? suction pump and a long handle to move the intake pipe around. Are you expecting a list of equipment?

Comment: Is there a washout plug at the bottom of the tank? Probably on the side. Fill one tank, pressure-blast the other tank to push the sand out the washout.  Exchange.

Comment: You have made some statements. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a _Question_ and Answer forum. Please [edit] your post to actually ask a question.

Comment: It will be easier to vacuum the sand out if you do NOT lower the water level.

Comment: Also, an appropriate filter can remove new sand before the water goes into the tank, and some are even easily blown clear of accumulated sand in the filter. So you would not have to do this again in the future.

Comment: I have found a Venturi vacuum is very effective at picking up sand, think “gold dredge” they are not hard to build out of pvc for this project. It can pick up just about everything your jet won’t need to be big once you create a syphon if you use a flex hose to drop out side the tank , don’t over fill it with sand or it will stall and you have to wait for the solids to drop and the jet will start flowing the sand and water again yes it will deposit both sand and water wherever the end of the pipe is and this uses a fair amount of water but works.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: a shop vac might be able to get a lot of it, might need some pvc extensions...